# generator-babel-boilerplate Browser-test

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using [generator-babel-boilerplate](https://github.com/babel/generator-babel-boilerplate//) and then running `npm run test-browser`.
This works without errors, but I need to test things in the browser, and I'm not sure how to see what is being served.

Using the following doesn't work:

- `localhost`
- `localhost:9000`
- `localhost:8080`

Where is it serving the files, if at all?

Comment: Are you sure that the command is `npm browser-test` instead of `npm test-browser`?

Comment: Yea actually it should be ```npm run test-browser```,but this is not the problem. I edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open runner.html file in your browser:

```
open ./test/runner.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this line in [generator-babel-boilerplate's source code](https://github.com/babel/generator-babel-boilerplate/blob/master/app/templates/gulpfile.babel.js#L158):

> ```
> $.livereload.listen({port: 35729, host: 'localhost', start: true});
> ```

So it appears that `localhost:35729` might work.

Comment: I tried that, I think that has to do with live reload only. Not what is being served up with webpack.

Comment: Isn't WebPack just a bundler? LiveReload is the only server there, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yea, webpack has a dev server, but its not in the package.json.  I dont think there is a server serving up the files.  Looking at other repos that use this generator, they are using gulp-connect with livereload.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell there is no server to serve up the files.

I needed to add the following to the gulpfile:

```js
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
    port: 7777,
    livereload: true,
    root: __dirname,
    https: false
  });
});

// then add connect to the test-browser tasks 
gulp.task('test-browser', ['connect', 'clean-tmp'], testBrowser);
```